# Running a scheduled zappa function manually

Tags: django, zappa

I want to test the event in zappa_settings.json locally

I have set up the environment and I have the server running a Django site on my local machine, I am also able to deploy the Django site to AWS via Zappa. Before pushing it to the cloud I would like to test the event which is used to deploy a cronjob to the cloud with Lambda functions. I keep getting errors on the imports.

Here is my Event in zappa_settings.json

```
"events": [{
     "function": "main.kpi_report.auto_scraper",
     "expression": "cron(20 12 * * ? *)"
     // "expression": "rate(10 minutes)"
     }],
```

Here are the imports in my kpi_report.py file

```
from .mws_settings import mws_settings
from .util import get_country_by_marketplace_name, date_amz_to_normal, process_currency
from .dynamodb import KPI
```

Python3 manage.py runserver

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly 
until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

October 03, 2019 - 12:23:46
Django version 2.0.7, using settings 'com.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Then finally when I run the auto_scrapper manually on my local machine:

```
t$ python main/kpi_report.py auto_scrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main/kpi_report.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .mws_settings import mws_settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.mws_settings'; '__main__' is not a package
(zappa_env) t$
```

I am not sure how to test the cron jobs ( events ) in Zappa. Its very inefficient to upload the code to the cloud and wait for the event to run and check the logs in Lambda. Please advice, TYIA

Answer (score 0):

you can try and just execute main.kpi_report.auto_scraper locally